# ReactEditText.java line 149

Tags: react-native

Reported specific device crash in android - react-native.

**ReactEditText.java line 149**

**com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactEditText$1.performAccessibilityAction**

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException setSpan (4 ... 4)
> ends beyond length 3

Comment: still having the same problem. did you find out why ?